# Null is not an Object StoreKit

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I followed this tutorial: 
https://fovea.cc/blog/index.php/3-steps-tutorial-for-phonegap-2x-in-app-purchase-on-ios/

But the list doesn't render and i get the error:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'el.innerHTML = "In-App Purchases not available."')

Any help much appreciated!

This is the code:

```
var IAP = {
  list: [ "unlockall" ]
};

IAP.load = function () {
  // Check availability of the storekit plugin
  if (!window.storekit) {
    console.log("In-App Purchases not available");
    return;
  }

  // Initialize
  storekit.init({
    ready:    IAP.onReady,
    purchase: IAP.onPurchase,
    restore:  IAP.onRestore,
    error:    IAP.onError
  });
};

// StoreKit's callbacks (we'll talk about them later)
IAP.onReady = function () {};
IAP.onPurchase = function () {};
IAP.onRestore = function () {};
IAP.onError = function () {};

IAP.onReady = function () {
    // Once setup is done, load all product data.
    storekit.load(IAP.list, function (products, invalidIds) {
      IAP.products = products;
      IAP.loaded = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < invalidIds.length; ++i) {
        console.log("Error: could not load " + invalidIds[i]);
      }
  });
};


var renderIAPs = function (el) {
  if (IAP.loaded) {
    var coins10  = IAP.products["unlockall"];
    var html = "<ul>";
    for (var id in IAP.products) {
      var prod = IAP.products[id];
      html += "<li>" +
       "<h3>" + prod.title + "</h3>" +
       "<p>" + prod.description + "</p>" +
       "<button type='button' " +
       "onclick='IAP.buy(\"" + id + "\")'>" +
       prod.price + "</button>" +
       "</li>";
    }
    html += "</ul>";
    el.innerHTML = html;
  }
  else {
    el.innerHTML = "In-App Purchases not available.";
  }
};

renderIAPs(document.getElementById('in-app-purchase-list'));

IAP.onPurchase = function (transactionId, productId, receipt) {
  if (productId === 'unlockall') {
    alert("GEKAUFT!");
  }
};

IAP.onError = function (errorCode, errorMessage) {
  alert('Error: ' + errorMessage);
};


IAP.buy = function (productId) {
  storekit.purchase(productId);
};


IAP.onRestore = function (transactionId, productId, transactionReceipt) {
  // Pseudo code that unlocks the full version.
  if (productId === 'unlockall') {
    FeatureManager.unlockEverything();
  }
};
IAP.restore = function () {
  storekit.restore();
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the id of the element right, and that that element exists at the moment that code runs?

Comment: This is what i have in index.html `<div id="in-app-purchase-list"> </div>` @nnnnnn